# How do I toggle on/off specific time periods in matlab simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a doubt on how to implement the following question in simulink matlab.

Create a logic that toggles on/off every 2 seconds for 30 seconds and toggles on/off every 1 second for the next 30 seconds. Continue this pattern for 1 hour. Check the output pattern in scope. for on scope output 1 and for off scope output 0.

I am new to simulink and matlab could you please help me with this question like how to approach. Thank you.

Comment: Use the `Pulse Generator` and `Step` blocks. The step block will allow you to set a value to be true/false for 30 seconds and the pulse generator will provide the toggle on/off periodically. If you AND these signals together you will get a wave that toggles on/off every 2 seconds for 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

**Toggles on/off every 2 seconds for 30 seconds**

- Step Block - Configure this with at step time of 30, initial value of 1, final value of 0.
- Pulse Generator - Configure period 2 seconds, pulse width 50%
- Connect the output of both of these blocks to an AND gate and place a scope on the output.

**Toggles on/off every 1 second for the next 30 seconds**

- Invert the signal from the first Step Block using a NOT gate.
- Add another Pulse Generator configured with a period of 1 second,
  pulse width of 50%.
- Connect the output of the NOT gate and this new Pulse Generator to an
  AND gate and connect the output to a scope.

If these two signals are supposed to be on the same output, connect the output of each and gate to an OR gate and then the output of this signal will be your desired waveform.

**Continue for an hour**

Set the model's stop time to be `60*60` which is the number of seconds in an hour.

Comment: Hey very much thanks to you for that answer. I will implement this and get back to you.

Comment: I implemented the model it worked for 60 seconds the on off pattern but for 3600 seconds it's not working. I have set stop time as 3600 seconds. Is there anything that I am missing ? Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem if you set the Stop Time to be 3600? Can you define what "not working" means in this context? What behaviour are you seeing?